# Ignore CSS in modal

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I am using ReactJS and ANTD. I have a modal which I have set paddings on such that the text are aligned in the center. Now, I want to add some design.
This is how I want it to look like: [image]

This is how it looks like now: [image]

CSS:

```
modalStyle {
   padding: 100px 50px
}
```

index.js

```
const styling ={
design:{
        background: "#FFFFFF",
        width: "400px",
        height: "30px",
        margin: "40px 50px 40px 0px !important"
    }
}

const Modal = props => {
return (

        <Modal
            className={"modalStyle"}

        > 
            <div style={styling.design}> </div>
        </Modal>
)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the important parts of this problem are all in CSS, both ReactJS and ANTD won't play much into the problem or the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a negative left margin into your inner div to counteract the padding from the modal container.

```
const styling ={
design:{
        ...otherStyles,
        margin: "40px 50px 40px -50px !important"
    }
}
```

This will actually it's contents go all the way to the left edge, so if you'd like to still have you text set further in, what you could do is add the padding on the div as well.

```
const styling ={
design:{
        ...otherStyles,
        margin: "40px 50px 40px -50px !important",
        padding: 100px 50px,
    }
}
```

Here's a sketch of an inner div growing past the margins of a modal https://codesandbox.io/s/counter-act-padding-in-child-o5y7z

IMHO, I think the best way to do this would be with `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements, I can try to add an example of that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using flex to do this,

//Component

```
<div className="modal">
    <div className="modal-bar" />
    <div className="modal-text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      minim veniam.
    </div>
    <div className="modal-bar" />
  </div>
```

//CSS

```
   .modal {
      width: 80%;
      height: 50vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
      margin: auto;
      background: #0075cb;
      border: 1px solid #0075cb;
      border-radius: 50px;
      padding: 50px 0;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .modal-bar {
      height: 50px;
      width: 100%;
      background: white;
    }

    .modal-text {
      padding: 50px;
      text-align: left;
    }
```

I have created a sandbox for the same
https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-brattain-kosui